# JSON data in search list

Tags: javascript, html, css, json

I have the below code, which you can search in the input and list of data will be in a drop down. but I want to know how I can change this to get the data from the JSON file instead of writing the list in `<li><a>...`

```
<input type="text" id="myInput" onkeyup="myFunction()" placeholder="Search for names.." title="Type in a name">

<ul id="myUL">
  <li><a href="#">Adele</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Agnes</a></li>

  <li><a href="#">Billy</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Bob</a></li>

  <li><a href="#">Calvin</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Christina</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Cindy</a></li>
</ul>

<script>
function myFunction() {
    var input, filter, ul, li, a, i;
    input = document.getElementById("myInput");
    filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
    ul = document.getElementById("myUL");
    li = ul.getElementsByTagName("li");
    for (i = 0; i < li.length; i++) {
        a = li[i].getElementsByTagName("a")[0];
        if (a.innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
            li[i].style.display = "";
        } else {
            li[i].style.display = "none";

        }
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: Let me confirm , json file or json data ...

Comment: I have this now on index.html file and the data.json in same folder

Answer (score 1):

First you can create the external file (example "data.json"):

```
[
    {"name":"Adele", "href":"#"},
    {"name":"Agnes","href":"#"},
    {"name":"Billy","href":"#"},
    {"name":"Bob","href":"#"},
    {"name":"Calvin","href":"#"},
    {"name":"Christina","href":"#"},
    {"name":"Cindy","href":"#"}
]
```

Then, you can define a function to update the UI with a data array:

```
function updateList(data) {
    var ul = document.getElementById('myUL');
    for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        var a = document.createElement('a');
        a.appendChild(document.createTextNode(data[i].name));
        a.setAttribute('href', data[i].href);
        var li = document.createElement('li');
        li.appendChild(a);
        ul.appendChild(li);
    }
}
```

You can import the json file using an AJAX request with native javascript:

```
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
request.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readystate == 4 && this.status == 200) {
        var data = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
        updateList(data);
    }
};
request.open("GET", "data.json", true);
request.send();
```

This code would then populate the existing UI element from the page:

```
<ul id="myUL"></ul>
```

Comment: Your data.json is not valid json, it's an javascript array of objects

Comment: thanks, do I still need to add <input type="text" id="myInput" onkeyup="myFunction()" placeholder="Search for names.." title="Type in a name">

Comment: I updated to ensure a valid JSON file and to load it properly with an AJAX request. Thanks @baao for catching my mistake.

Comment: Yes, @charlie97, this will still work with your search code

Comment: I edited it for you. Now it's valid json. You need to enclose everything in `"` (also the keys), and `'` is not valid

Comment: Sorry was reading through it too quickly...thought you were referring to how the file was being loaded. Agree on the formatting - wasn't even checking that.

Comment: @baao thank you but nothing is working, i have all the javascript and html in index.html file and the data.json file in the same folder as that but still not working, in the console says:Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https.

Comment: @charlie97, the CORS issue happens if you're loading the HTML page straight from a browser ("file://" protocol instead of "http" or "https"). It will work fine once it is on a web server or if you can host it from a local web server (IIS, node, or whatever flavor you prefer)

Comment: @JasonW thanks, I had the data in the same file and found out I was missing the : $( document ).ready(function() { )};

Comment: Didn't realize you were using JQuery. It could be a lot simpler syntax - look up the `$.getJSON` function to load your file from external source instead of all the vanilla xml http request handling - very easy to use.

Answer (score 0):

**Try this :**

```js
 var jsonObj = [
    {"name":"Adele","link":"Adele.html"},
    {"name":"Agnes","link":"Agnes.html"},
    {"name":"Billy","link":"Billy.html"},
    {"name":"Bob","link":"Bob.html"},
    {"name":"Calvin","link":"Calvin.html"},
    {"name":"Christina","link":"Christina.html"},
    {"name":"Cindy","link":"Cindy.html"}
]
 
 for(i=0; i < jsonObj.length; i++)
 {
   var li=document.createElement('li');
   li.innerHTML="<a href='"+ jsonObj[i].link +"'>"+ jsonObj[i].name +"</a>";
   document.getElementById('myUL').appendChild(li);
 }
 
document.getElementById('myInput').addEventListener('keyup', function(e) {
    var filteredResult = jsonObj.filter(obj => {
      return obj.name.includes(e.key) === true;
    });
    document.getElementById('myUL').innerHTML = '';
     for(i=0; i < filteredResult.length; i++)
     {
       var li=document.createElement('li');
       li.innerHTML="<a href='"+ filteredResult[i].link +"'>"+ filteredResult[i].name +"</a>";
       document.getElementById('myUL').appendChild(li);
     }
});
```

```html
<input type="text" id="myInput" placeholder="Search for names.." title="Type in a name">

<ul id="myUL"></ul>
```

Comment: thanks for this, I did paste all this code into my index.html file with the script inside the script tags but when I open on browser, the console says :  Cannot read property 'appendChild' of null and it doesnt work, what is the issue? am i missing something

Comment: Make sure your `ul` element should have `id="myUL"` as we are append the child on this id only.

Comment: is there a way to add the keydown method to this function so user can select option with keyboard arrows please?

Comment: i used the above code but now i realised that the search brings a random name like cindy when i type ad, is it just searching for a letter within the words? the search isnt working well.

Comment: @charlie97 As there is no dropdown to select the options. we have only one search box. Hence, only `keyup` event will work in that case.

Comment: oh ok basically i am not using the option select UI, just want to bring all the json data in a drop down from the search, i have this working with the code above without json data, where its all manually written in HTML, but wanted to have them as a json instead.

Comment: As per OP if my answer is useful please mark it as correct so that it will be useful for others as well.